# How to pass default values in common-lib that has spring dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a common-lib jar that is shared with multiple microservices that use spring-boot. How can I define some environment values in the common-lib such that if I find the values in application.properties of microservices it is overridden else default values in library will be used. Can I have application.properties in common-lib and if the same keys are found in microservice those keys will be overwritten. I am using spring-boot 2.6.2 and Java 11.

Eg . I have configuration class to connect to activeMq in common-lib . If keys are defined in microservice application.properties for configuration they will be picked for connection else some default keys present in the library itself will be picked .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have properties files in your libraries and use `PropertySource` (just a note it works only with properties and not with yaml because it is not Spring Boot annotation). I have this configuration in my library:

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:library.properties")
public class DefaultLibraryConfiguration {
}
```

and `library.properties`. You just need to import this configuration class for example:

```java
@Import(DefaultLibraryConfiguration.class)
```

or create an autoconfiguration.
Properties can be overridden in your `application.properties`